# Struts2 configuration conflict in Eclipse using Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, configuration, struts2

I'm upgrading some old legacy applications to Maven. These applications run in WebSphere Application Server traditional 8.5.5 and I'm using Eclipse 4.16.0 to run the WAS server.

It compiles just fine, however, when I try to access web applications that are built with Struts, I have the following error message in the browser:

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [struts2]: could not be initialized
```

And, in the server logs, I have this:

```
[30/05/23 10:37:26:986 BRT] 000000b6 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor]: Unable to load configuration. - bean - wsjar:file:/C:/Users/DouglasCanevarollo/Desktop/ibm/evs/evs-maven/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/evs-ip-upload/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-6.1.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:116:72
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:566)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:48)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:60)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:145)
...
Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name struts has already been loaded by bean - wsjar:file:/C:/Users/DouglasCanevarollo/.m2/repository/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/6.1.2/struts2-core-6.1.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:116:72 - bean - wsjar:file:/C:/Users/DouglasCanevarollo/Desktop/ibm/evs/evs-maven/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/evs-ip-upload/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-6.1.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:116:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:263)
    ... 34 more
```

How can I solve this conflict?

These are my Struts configuration files:

**struts.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 6.0.//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-6.0.dtd">
 <struts>
    ...
 
    <!-- Package -->
    <package name="default" namespace="/protect" extends="struts-default">
    
        <!-- Action Mappings -->
        <action name="uploadIpDb" method="runInit" class="com.ibm.comexp.ipupload.action.IPUploadAction" >
            <result>/home.jsp</result>
        </action>
        ...
    </package>

 </struts>
```

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    
    ...
    
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I think we're also going to need any part of your `web.xml` that refers to the `com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory` type, as it is explicitly mentioned in the error message.

Comment: @nitind, my `web.xml` doesn't have anything much else... only default configurations like  `<display-name/>`, a `<servlet/>` that points to our logging common servlet and a environment entry for `com.ibm.webstandards.WebStandardFromRequest`. Is that what you've asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name struts has already been loaded by

Don't use the same library twice on the classpath `struts2-core-6.1.2.jar`. The struts configuration contains in this library in the `struts-default.xml`. It should be loaded only once when struts2 filter is initialized. Remove the duplicate library from the classpath after deploy of your application.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. However, I'm not setting the classpath. I'm using Maven to compile the application.

Comment: If you use Maven then you have probably set dependency on struts2-core, but the same library is already existing on the server or is renamed to different file name and your server logs are created not at compile time but at run time when your application is deployed. Also you didn't post `pom.xml`, so it's unclear how did you build your application.